# Dropdown menu not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to my navigation bar using bootstrap. The menu is displayed on top of the button and one item isn't displayed.

Here is a full jsfiddle of my html + css: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvbfvjzm/10/)

Here is the code that I'm using to create the dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <div class="animMenu dropdown-toggle" id="imgMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div class="menuBar1"></div>
            <div class="menuBar2"></div>
            <div class="menuBar3"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Backup Assistant</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

You can access the menu by clicking the icon with the 3 bars.

The animMenu div consists of 3 bars and it turns into a cross when clicked with an animation, it's not a regular image like the other icons.

Any ideas on how to get the menu positioned underneath the button. I tried adding btn to the toggle classes but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Remove overflow hidden** 
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: calc(100% - 203px);
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}
**And write in place of it** 
div.tab {
     overflow: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: calc(100% - 203px);
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

after that your code working fine

Comment: Thanks! That makes all the items visible but it's still on top of the button and not under it, do you know a solution for this as well?

Comment: Yes  please set the property of class .dropdown-menu{top: 45px !important}

Comment: @user265889 `.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50px;
}` (set the top accordingly)

Comment: Only .dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right { top: 50px; } now it working. you facing any problem right now

Comment: I was having an issue where my drop-down was going behind the lower level and the `overflow-inherit` fixed my issue, so I the +1 is mine. I was not dealing with animated icons as the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

just add that to css

```
 .dropdown-menu {
  top: 50px;
 }
```

That's will override the bootstrap css class dropdown-menu class or 
you can use which is specified

```
 .tab .dropdown-menu {
  top: 50px;
 }
```

or add new specified class to tab class